# Prove that $L^p\left ( \mathbb R^n, e^{\frac{-1}2 |x|^2} \right)\cap \theta(\mathbb R^n)$ is infinite dimensional

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, lp-spaces, harmonic-functions

> Prove that the space
> $$L^p\left ( \mathbb R^n, e^{\frac{-1}2 |x|^2} \right)\cap \theta(\mathbb R^n)$$
> is infinite dimensional for $1\le p\le \infty$.

Here, $\theta(\mathbb R^n)$ is the set of all harmonic functions on $\mathbb R^n$. I have proved in a previous exercise that the space
$$L^p(\mathbb R^n)\cap \theta(\mathbb R^n)$$
only contains constant functions ($0$ function if $p<\infty$).

But, I do not have any idea about proving this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to assume $n \geq 2$, else you only have functions of the form
$$
f(x)=ax+b.
$$
You know that with $z=x_1+ix_2$
$$
f(z)=z^m
$$
is holomorphic for any $m>0$ and hence
$$
\Re(f(z))
$$
is a (real-vaued) harmonic polynomial in the variables $x_1,x_2$.

Furthermore, any polynomial is in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n,e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x|^2}dx)$.

But now there are infinitely many: The real part of $(x_1+ix_2)^m$ is also a polynomial of degree $m$ and hence these polynomials are linearly independent for different choices of $m$. Therefore, the subspace
$$
\{ \Re((x_1+ix_2)^m) \mid m \in \mathbb{N} \} \subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^n,e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x|^2}dx) \cap \theta(\mathbb{R}^n)
$$
is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: That was clever, thanks (+1)!

Comment: You are welcome. I just thought this was the way to go, since you tagged complex analysis. There are surely other ways, using the fundamental solution.